# What's the word "here" in "It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us

This sentence is from the article *The Gettysburg Address*/ I am really confused about the word "here" in "here be dedicated to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must look at it in context.

> But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate
> -- we can not hallow -- this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled **here**, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to
> add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we
> say **here**, but it can never forget what they did **here**. It is for us the
> living, rather, to be dedicated **here** to the unfinished work which they
> who fought **here** have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us
> to be **here** dedicated to the great task remaining before us -- that
> from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for
> which they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we **here**
> highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that
> this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that
> government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not
> perish from the earth.

Seven instances of *here* in one paragraph! What this shows is that the Address is strongly tied to the place it was given. Because they are on a battlefield, the repeated use of *here* evokes strong emotion about the battle, the war, and the idea of America.

Grammatically and semantically, it does not contribute much to the sentence it is in.* But rhetorically, you can see it contributes a lot.

*You could argue that, if taken literally, it actually *detracts* from the sentiment---we assume that the audience will be dedicated to the great task remaining not only while they are on the actual battlefield, but also after they have left it. But such grammatical nit-picking clearly ignores the rhetorical force of the entire paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It's speaking to a group of people gathered in a location to hear the speech. It means "in this location, on this occasion".